# Sqlite Insert error in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I am using sqlite and I try to insert some data to sqlite database.It is not work. I have a one table which name is LabUpdate but  I have some errors like this:

```
2012-04-02 08:49:58.158 SqliteDeneme[361:207] Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  no such column: deneme
2012-04-02 08:49:58.159 SqliteDeneme[361:207] Compiled Statement has error code:1:INSERT    INTO LabUpdate (IsSuccess, ProducerId, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Slope, SampleDate,    PackageNo, Status, Description)    VALUES(1,1,0.100000,0.100000,0.100000,0.100000,deneme,1,1,deneme)
2012-04-02 08:49:58.160 SqliteDeneme[361:207] ExecuteNonQuery has error
2012-04-02 08:49:58.160 SqliteDeneme[361:207] Failed from sqlite3_step. Error is:  library routine called out of sequence
```

My code like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {

NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SqliteTestDb.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
}
if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &cruddb) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
}

if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &cruddb) ==SQLITE_OK){

int  str1 =1;
int str2 =1;
float str3 =0.1;
float str4 =0.1;
float str5 =0.1;
float str6 =0.1;
NSString *str7 =@"deneme";
int str8 =1;
int str9 =1;
NSString *str10=@"deneme";

NSString* SQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LabUpdate (IsSuccess, ProducerId, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Slope, SampleDate, PackageNo, Status, Description) VALUES(%i,%i,%f,%f,%f,%f,%@,%i,%i,%@)",str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10];

stmt = [self prepare:SQL];

    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt); 
    sqlite3_close(cruddb);

if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) 
{
    NSLog(@"ExecuteNonQuery has error");
    NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_step. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb) );

}
else
{
    int rowsaffected = sqlite3_changes(cruddb);
    NSLog(@" rowsaffected %i",rowsaffected);
}

}
}

-(sqlite3_stmt*)prepare:(NSString*)query
{
sqlite3_stmt *queryHandle;


const char *sqlStatement = (const char *) [query UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sqlStatement, -1, &queryHandle, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
    int error = sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sqlStatement, -1, &queryHandle, NULL);

    NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb) );

    NSLog(@"Compiled Statement has error code:%i:%@",error,query);
}

return queryHandle;
}
```

what is the problem? How can I solve this? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not that it really answers your question, but I thoroughly recommend using an Objective-C sqlite wrapper like FMDB or PLDatabase - it'll make your life so much easier.

Comment: can you post a NSLog(@"SQL: %@", SQL ) ? But you should quote mark your strings! e.g. : NSString* SQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LabUpdate (IsSuccess, ProducerId, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Slope, SampleDate, PackageNo, Status, Description) VALUES(%i,%i,%f,%f,%f,%f,'%@',%i,%i,'%@')",str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8,str9,str10];

Comment: For some reason you are executing `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and if that fails you are executing it **again** in order to get the error code.  That is nonsense; do it in one step.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to run an SQL statement, everything that is not a number needs to be quoted e.g.

```
INSERT INTO foo (column1, column2) VALUES ('bar' , 'baz');
                                        // ^^^^^   ^^^^^ string values quoted.
```

However, I **strongly** recommend using [sqlite3_bind](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) instead of formatting values directly into your SQL statement.